# How to get numbers from a string in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file name stored in the $FILE variable in a shell script, for example:

$FILE = application-231241223.tar

There can be different .tar file names stored there. One thing they all have in common is that there is a number before the .tar

I need to store this number, regardless of its length, in the $PROCESS_NUMBER variable

The file name can also be application-2412-test-12312333.tar or application-2412-test12312333.tar

The only thing I need to store is the numbers before the .tar until the occurrence of a character other than a number. The length of the number can also be different.

Can anyone advise me how to do this

I tried this and it didn't work

```
export PROCESS_NUMBER=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\)\.tar/\1')
export PROCESS_NUMBER=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/.*([0-9]+)\.tar/\1/g')
export PROCESS_NUMBER=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/')
export PROCESS_NUMBER=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/.*-\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\.tar/\1/')
```

Comment: Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: Regarding "... until the occurrence of a character other than a number" - could that character be something other than the `.` from `.tar`? If so, please include an example of that in your question.

Comment: Regarding "it didn't work" - that's the worst possible problem statement as it tells us nothing we could use to help you debug your code. [edit] your question to state in what way it didn't work - wrong output, no output, error messages, etc. Also add what version of `sed` you're running (try `sed --version`).

Answer (score 2):

One `bash` idea using a regex and the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array:

```
regex='([0-9]+)\.tar'

for fname in application-231241223.tar application-2412-test-12312333.tar application-2412-test12312333.tar
do
    echo "###### $fname"
    [[ "$fname" =~ $regex ]] && typeset -p BASH_REMATCH
done
```

This generates:

```
###### application-231241223.tar
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="231241223.tar" [1]="231241223")
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
###### application-2412-test-12312333.tar
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="12312333.tar" [1]="12312333")
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
###### application-2412-test12312333.tar
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="12312333.tar" [1]="12312333")
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The value we're looking for is in the `BASH_REMATCH[1]` location so OP's code becomes:

```
regex='([0-9]+)\.tar'

for fname in application-231241223.tar application-2412-test-12312333.tar application-2412-test12312333.tar
do
    [[ "$fname" =~ $regex ]] && export PROCESS_NUMBER="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

---

An alternative using parameter expansion:

```
for fname in application-231241223.tar application-2412-test-12312333.tar application-2412-test12312333.tar
do
    echo "###### $fname"
    newfname="${fname%.tar}"
    newfname="${newfname##*[^0-9]}"
    typeset -p newfname
done
```

This generates:

```
###### application-231241223.tar
declare -- newfname="231241223"
                     ^^^^^^^^^
###### application-2412-test-12312333.tar
declare -- newfname="12312333"
                     ^^^^^^^^
###### application-2412-test12312333.tar
declare -- newfname="12312333"
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

OP's code becomes:

```
for fname in application-231241223.tar application-2412-test-12312333.tar application-2412-test12312333.tar
do
    newfname="${fname%.tar}"
    export PROCESS_NUMBER="${newfname##*[^0-9]}"
done
```

Comment: In the regex version, thanks to the greedy quantifier, the leading `[^0-9]` is not strictly required. And the dot in `.tar` should be escaped.

Comment: Missing a `$` at the end of the regex (for safety).

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash's [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to replace all non-digits with spaces, then retrieve the last block of numbers by iterating over its words. Example:

```bash
FILE="application-2412-test-12312333.tar"
PROCESS_NUMBER="${FILE//[^0-9]/ }"
for PROCESS_NUMBER in $PROCESS_NUMBER; do :; done
echo "$PROCESS_NUMBER"
```

```
12312333
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and as it always finishes in `.tar` (thus the -4)

```
awk -F '[^0-9]' '{print $(NF-4)}'
```